# Save image from URL without form (Symfony 3)

Tags: image, symfony, download, controller

I want to save an image (from URL) and relocate it to another folder without creating a form, into a controller. How can I realize it?

Download image inside Controller -> relocate it to another folder -> save image name into my database (in an existing table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is broad and you don't specify if you are using Doctrine DBAL and ORM and what exactly your problem is, so I will assume that you do use them and you are aware how to inject entity manager inside a controller action.

First you have to download the image and save the image:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://example.com/image.jpg");

//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen("/location/to/save/image.jpg", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

Then save the path into the database:

```
$imageEntity->setPath('image.jpg');
$entityManager->flush($imageEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you! I try to save the image which was generated via https://www.thum.io/. As a result, a try to do following -> $fp = fopen($uploadDirectory . '/image.png', "w"); fwrite($fp, $screenshotUrl); fclose($fp);    And...I can observe that image have bad extension (tried png, jpeg). What's wrong?

Comment: You are trying to pass $screenshotUrl as second argument in fwrite, when you should pass $content. Did you use file_get_contents()?

Comment: Oh....I forgot that it's not an image...only url. Thank you very much. You save my life!